# Asp classic and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have a asp form with bunch of fields that I would like to implement ajax to it.

I'm wondering what would be the best way and beginner way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "implement ajax to it"? Is it a form that you wish to submit using ajax?

Comment: Ajax to do WHAT exactly? Submit to server for validation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common task. Here is a basic jQuery example of using ajax to submit a form:

```
var formData = $("#frmAction").serialize();

$.ajax({
   url: "url to ajax page",
   dataType: "json",
   type: "POST",
   data: formData,
   success: function() {
      alert("success");
   },
   error: function() {
      alert("error");
   }
});
```